# Set up GruntJS watch script in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, gruntjs, watch

I've got Grunt configured just the way i want it, and everything works as it should. But being the lazy developer i am, instead of having to open up the command line and type `grunt watch` every time i open the project, i thought i could just create a Windows Batch file in the project root folder, and run that file.

I figured it would look something like:

```
grunt watch
pause
```

But that just endlessly loops `<path> grunt watch`. I also tried `call grunt watch` and `start grunt watch`. The latter did not end well.

Is this not possible to do? If it is, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: just using `grunt watch` by itself doesn't work in the batch file? Without the `pause` I mean?

Comment: That was what i thought at first. It just loops this: http://i.imgur.com/Yne4BKJ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably named it `grunt.bat` so when invoked, it calls itself and endlessly loops.

There are two simple solutions

1. Either call your bat with another name, `g.bat` for example, and invoke it simply as `g`
2. Or change the contents to specifically invoke the `grunt` script, with a fully specified path

Comment: I too made this mistake. D'oh!